# Descriptor behavior when accessing a dict's key

Tags: python, dictionary, lazy-loading, descriptor

I am implementing some sort of lazy loading. I have a dict, with each key's value being an empty list. When I access a key, I need to run some loading logic to populate the corresponding list with some values.

So, when I create the dictionary (let's name it `d`) there are some keys created: `a:[], b:[]`. Now, when I access a key in the dictionary: `d['a']` I need to run some logic that basically returns a computed list (let's say `[1, 2, 3]`) and the `d` dict becomes: `a: [1, 2, 3], b:[]`.

I hope I explained things well enough. In my knowledge, this is something similar to descriptors in Python since you can attach custom logic to an *attribute*. But what I need here is attaching custom logic to a dict's *keys*, which surely doesn't work with descriptors.

Is there a way of doing this? Or maybe I could use descriptors but in some other manner?

Comment: The empty list is the key or the value of the dict when created?

Comment: It looks like you want something like https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault

Comment: As far as I am aware, a list cannot be a key of a dict. The empty lists are assigned by default to the dict's keys (which are themselves computed by some logic).

Comment: @AndreiHorak that´s why I´m asking, you wrote: *I have a dict, with each key being an empty list*, that´s wrong.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, seen now and corrected my error.

Comment: If you're not bound to use plain empty lists - you could think about making the values lazy, rather than the access to the keys. In a sense that the values are only really loaded when they're first used for whatever...

Comment: @AndreiHorak answer edited, I think that what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply implement that logic in `__getitem__`:

```
class LazyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LazyDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # init a set which will keep the already loaded keys
        self._loaded = set()

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if item in self and item not in self._loaded:
            # do the "lazy" action
            self[item] = some_function(item)
            self._loaded.add(item)
        # return the value
        return super(LazyDict, self).__getitem__(self, item)
```

Where `some_function` would be whatever populates the individual keys.
If your unloaded keys are always empty lists, `__getitem__` could also look like this:

```
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        value = super(LazyDict, self).__getitem__(self, item)
        if not value:
            value = self[item] = some_function(item)
        return value
```

This version would not need the extra `_loaded` set to keep track of which keys are loaded or not.

Comment: As I commented in @Raydel Miranda's answer, the values from my dict are wrapped in a class, otherwise this would've been my solution too.

Comment: I don't understand how that speaks against my (or @Raydel's, FWIW) solution. A descriptor works on attributes almost just like `__getitem__` does for keys. So if you want any non-default action before getting a key, you'll have to modify `__getitem__`

Comment: That's exactly my idea, there is too much logic which is unrelated to the dict and I moved it to a separate class. So when I get a dict's key, an object of my class is retrieved, and upon the retrieval I need to trigger some action in that object for my custom logic. Exactly how `__get__` works when accessing a descriptor.

Comment: Well you're not really forced to move that code literally to the dict...? You could even make `some_function` an input parameter of the `LazyDict`. Using a descriptor that code would also have to become part of your modified `dict` class...

Comment: Alright, it seems this is the best idea so far. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can specialize `dict` class.

```
class MyDict(dict):
    # __init__ here is redundant - it can safely be ommited.
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print("Getting item")
        return super(MyDict, self).__getitem__(key)


d = MyDict()
d[4] = 8
print(d[4])
```

That prints:

```
>>> Getting item
>>> 8
```

### Approach using a decorator

```
class FunctionRel:
    def __init__(self):

        self.rel = {
            1: self.function_1,
            2: self.function_2,
            3: self.function_3,
        }

    def __call__(self, key):
        return self.rel[key]()

    def function_1(self): return [1,1,1]
    def function_2(self): return [2,2,2]
    def function_3(self): return [3,3,3]


def wrapper(func):
    rel = FunctionRel()
    def black_magic(d, key, **kwargs):
        if key not in d.visited_keys:
            l = rel(key)
            d[key] = l
            d.visited_keys.append(key)
        return l
    return black_magic



class MyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.visited_keys = [] # Avoid recirsion in __getitem__ wrapper.
        super(MyDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @wrapper
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return super(MyDict, self).__getitem__(key)


d = MyDict()
print(d[1])
print(d[2])
print(d[3])
```

Ouput:

```
>>> [1,1,1]
>>> [2,2,2]
>>> [3,3,3]
```

Comment: Note that your `__init__` here is redundant - it can safely be ommited

Comment: This is my current approach, but since there is pretty much logic to be done with the dict's value, I wrapped the value in a separate class. That's why I feel that class would work great if it could be a descriptor.

Comment: And what about using your class as decorator some way of the __getitem__ method of the class `MyDict`?

Comment: Sounds interesting, can you further detail your idea?

Comment: Furthermore, there isn't a single wrapping object for the dict's values. There are several wrapper classes for those values, each having a slightly different behavior.

Comment: And this behaviour depends on keys?

Comment: Yes, depending on the key, one of the several wrapper classes is used as a value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59823/discussion-between-raydel-miranda-and-andrei-horak).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. It looks a bit too overkill for what I need and I will go with the other approach. Nonetheless, will keep this in mind as it's pretty neat!

Answer (score -3):

As you have the values as empty list, you can check for the first time if d[key] is empty list, then use a function to get appropriate values. If there is a chance that the value returned from the function be an empty list, you might want to use another dictionary to track which keys have been accessed so far.